# Promise.all not working when it's returned from a .then() callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using Promise Node.js library and I'd like to do the following:

1. Execute async operation that returns a Promise.
2. When that operation completes, return a Promise that is completed when two paralell async operations complete.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
var Promise = require('promise');

var resolved1 = Promise.resolve(1);

var resolvedAll = resolved1.then(function() {
  return Promise.all(Promise.resolve(2), Promise.resolve(3));
});

var print = resolvedAll.then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});

print.done(function () {
  console.log('done');
});
```

But this code is not working as expected, since it prints:

```
[]
done
```

From docu, Promise.all returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved. So in theory resolvedAll should not complete until all the promises passed to `Promise.all` have completed, but that's not what is happening here.

Any idea why Promise.all not working as expected? Could this be a bug? Anyone aware of alternatives to return multiple promises out of a `.then()` callback?

Cheers,
Galder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Promise.all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise#promiseallarray) expects an array:

```js
Promise.all([Promise.resolve(2), Promise.resolve(3)]);
```

Comment: Damm, that's my Java varargs expectations getting in the way. Thanks!